# Set artwork for music file in iOS iTunes Library (Jailbreak)

Tags: ios, jailbreak, itunes-app, itunesartwork

There is a good open-source library that uses Apple's private frameworks to add audio file to the iTunes library on a jailbroken iOS device, [libipodimport](https://github.com/H2CO3/libipodimport). What it's missing is the ability to also add artwork when adding a music file (one contributor checked in [code](https://github.com/H2CO3/libipodimport/commit/fc74d693ecb05ca06fb3db280df9c8f40d6da10f) that should do this, but the author later removed it as it didn't work).

Does anyone know what was missing from the code in libipodimport (see previous link), or perhaps an alternative way of adding artwork files to a music file?

Comment: Nice to see a question about my own library :) Well, work is still in progress, this really is annoying and a lot of people ask for this feature. I didn't have much time since I released this library but I'm looking forward to continue reverse engineering to see what is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah I understand, just hope maybe someone else can step in here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contributor to libipodimport told me the missing line that made the artwork adding work:

```
// metad is a SSDownloadMetadata object, see libipodimport for rest of code
[metad setFullSizeImageURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[userInfo objectForKey:kIPIKeyArtworkPath]]];
```

It seems to only work with jpeg files, not png files.

The library libipodimport will most likely be updated by the author in the near future.